# Python - Test if an element exists on an other list (no matter the place in the list)

Tags: python, list

I would like to do something like

```
list = [1,5,56,2]
listWin = [3,85,1,5]
```

I want to check if any of the *list* numbers exist in the *listWin* and say which numbers exist in each other.

Comment: what have you tried? What part of the problem are you struggling with? Do you know how to search for an item in a list? Do you know how to iterate over a list?

Comment: one line - `[print i for i in list if i in listWin]` . 
btw,  you shouldn't name your variables with reserved keywords of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to find the common elements. Also, don't use a built-in name `list` as a variable name.

```
In [1]: list1 = [1,5,56,2] # First list 

In [2]: list2 = [3,85,1,5] # Second list

In [3]: common_elements = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]

In [4]: common_elements # Common elements in 2 lists
Out[4]: [1, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! :D I don't know why people disliked my question :c I just lost some reputation omg not my fault if I am not a pro at python

Answer (score 3):

```
set(list).intersection(listWin)
```